# Date field shows {NAME} error instead of date - php/html

Tags: php, html

Update: 
It looks like it is very complicated as I have had many views but no comments, could someone tell me how to check through the array {NAME} to find where it loses it's content please?

Original question:
I have been debugging an older php script and this is the last bit where I am struggling. The date does not show up when I have the drop down list:

This is what the output is in HTML:

```
<select name="trans_date2_month" style="width: {WIDTH}" >           
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
    <option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
</select>
```

Could someone help to find out how to track back in php please? I am more than happy to give more code's but I didn't want to overload the first page.

This was generated by the following code:

```
<!--S:DateSelectOption-->
<option value="{VALUE}" {SELECTED}>{NAME}</option>
<!--E:DateSelectOption-->
```

**How to find {`value`} and {`name`}?** - (please don't say that the search bar will help - I have done it:)

Update:

```
case "year":
    if ($field["fields"]["year"]["empty"] == "true") {
        $years[0] = "--" ;
    }

    for ($i = $field["fields"]["year"]["from"] ; $i <= $field["fields"]["year"]["to"] ; $i++ )
        $years[$i] = $i;                                    

    $current_field .= $html->FormSelect(
        $field["name"]."_year" , 
        $years , 
        $this->templates , 
        "DateSelect", 
        $year_selected , 
        array() , 
        array("DISABLED" => ($field["fields"]["year"]["editable"] == "false") ? "DISABLED" : "")
    );

    $current_field .= $val["separator"];

break;
```

Update II:

A little bit more code, after searching for name... as a bad habit...

```
function HNDCData($parser,$cdata) {
        $cdata = str_replace("[amp]","&",$cdata);
        //echo "<br>" . $cdata;
        // create the proper tree node if NAME attribute is set
        if ($this->attr["NAME"] != "")
            $this->tags[count($this->tags) - 1] = $this->attr["NAME"];

        // cleanup cdata
        $cdata = trim($cdata);
        //$cdata = preg_replace("/(\015\012)|(\015)|(\012)/","",$cdata);

        // only parse if cdata not void
        if ($cdata != "") {
            //print_r($this->attr);
            //echo "<br>" . $cdata;

            // prepare dynamic code
            foreach ($this->tags as $key => $val)
                $code[] = "\"" . strtolower($val) . "\"";

            // build code
            $code = "\$this->vars[" . implode("][",$code) . "] = \"" . $cdata . "\";";

            // and finally execute
            eval($code);
        }
    }
```

Update: 
I have changed the for loop to numbers rather than variables but no difference.

for ($i = 2004 ; $i <= 2050 ; $i++ )

Comment: You've asked about a PHP question, yet posted no PHP code. Please post your PHP code. Don't worry about "overloading the first page" - The more information you give, the easier it is to help!

Comment: Sorry I have just realised so I have done an update. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are u using any templates(handle-bar,etc) to display the data and what date is it displaying now

Comment: as I can see it, it is a very basic concept picks the today's date and  will show it as a drop down menu no jquery or other fancy stuff.